# Aggregate rows with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `df` as below

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "b",
                          "b", "c", "c"),
                 col2 = c("x1", "x1.1", "x2", "x2.1", "x3", "x3.1"),
                 col3 = c(1, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA),
                 col4 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, 3))
df
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    a   x1    1   NA
2    a x1.1   NA    1
3    b   x2    2   NA
4    b x2.1   NA    2
5    c   x3    3   NA
6    c x3.1   NA    3
```

I want to merge rows that have the same letter in column `col1` and filter rows in column `col2` by telling them `col2 %in% c(x1,x1.1) & col2 %in% c(x2,x2.1) & col3 %in% (x3,x3.1)`, simulatenously.

My desired output would be:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    a   x1    1   1
2    b   x2    2   2
3    c   x3    3   3
```

One solution from my side is to call if `x == "x1"`, then `col4` will be filled by values assosicated with `x == "x1.1"`

Any suggestions for this to `group_by` `col1`? Thank you in advance!

**Additional note**

I did draw a pic for visualization, that I think would be easier for you to imagine.

[image]

The values in the actual dataset are different from the example here.

**Updated solution**
I found a solution with the help of akrun see here: [Use ~separate after mutate and across](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69789751/use-separate-after-mutate-and-across/69789799#69789799)

```
df |> 
  mutate(col2 = substring(col2, 1,2)) |> 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace(., is.na(.), "")) |> 
  group_by(col1, col2) |> 
  summarise(across(c(col3, col4), ~toString(.)), .groups = "drop") |> 
  mutate(col3 = str_remove(col3, ",")) |> 
  mutate(col4 = str_remove(col4, ", "))
```

I'm still open to further suggestions, if anyone has any.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but for your example data the approach below works:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(col2 = sub("\\.[0-9]+$", "", col2),
         col3 = coalesce(col3, col4),
         col4 = coalesce(col4, col3)) %>% 
  distinct()
#>   col1 col2 col3 col4
#> 1    a   x1    1    1
#> 2    b   x2    2    2
#> 3    c   x3    3    3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I think I confused you. Let's me edit my question. The output is what exactly I need but like my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

After extracting only the first to characters of `col2`, you can use `coalesce` to bring `col3` and `col4` together.
Then replacing `NA` by data from the coalesced column and using `distinct` at the end will lead to the desired output.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "b",
                          "b", "c", "c"),
                 col2 = c("x1", "x1.1", "x2", "x2.1", "x3", "x3.1"),
                 col3 = c(1, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA),
                 col4 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, 3))


df |> 
  mutate(col2 = substring(col2, 1,2)) |> 
  mutate(mycol = coalesce(col3, col4)) |>
  mutate(col3 = if_else(is.na(col3), mycol, col3),
         col4 = ifelse(is.na(col4), mycol, col4)) |> 
  select(-c(mycol)) |> 
  distinct()
#>   col1 col2 col3 col4
#> 1    a   x1    1    1
#> 2    b   x2    2    2
#> 3    c   x3    3    3
```

Comment: Let's me edit my question. Something is missing here